# interactive shell and C compilation inside emacs

Tags: shell, shell-command

I compiled a simple program in C (it does the sum of 2 numbers), by doing :

```
M-x compile RET
gcc -dummy.c -o dummy
M-x shell RET
./dummy
```

I get a prompt for the first number I can enter, then nothing is happening. I mean I can enter the first number, do RET, enter the second number (even though I don't have the prompt for this one) and I can get the result with Ctrl-D.
So, very ugly.
Any idea what is happening under the hood and what I should do to improve that?
Thanks

here is the code :

```
int main()
{
    int nb1,nb2;
    printf("please enter nb1");
    scanf("%d \n", &nb1);
    printf("please enter nb2");
    scanf("%d \n", &nb2);
    printf("the sum:");
    printf("%d + %d = %d", nb1, nb2, nb1 + nb2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One solution is to use M-x term or M-x ansi-term.  This will give you a real terminal emulator instead of shell-mode.

Comment: @Qudit : please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: The problem with `shell-mode` is that it needs you to send and read full lines. So, when you do `printf()` it doesn't know the program finished printing. If you add `\n` to your `printf()`, I believe it will work in `shell-mode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use M-x term or M-x ansi-term.  This will give you a real terminal emulator instead of shell-mode.

Comment: Thanks, one thing I have to do now is making the shell  buffer open in place of the compilation window...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want to accomplish.  Maybe you could make it a new question though

Comment: Yeah, it was not that clear, I've opened a new topic (http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28354/open-the-shell-buffer-in-the-same-frame-as-compilation-buffer-c-compilation). Thanks